# Are grace note pairs and a mordent played differently?

Tags: piano, ornaments

[image]

When I play the mordent and the graces notes highlighted, they sound the same. Should they be approached differently? Why would they be notated differently?

Comment: What period of style are we talking about here?

Comment: @lazy, it’s a Chopin waltz

Comment: Waltz in A minor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is timing. The grace notes happen *before* the primary note; the mordent happens *after* (or rather *during*) it.

You can play it with more freedom than this, but here's a rough way to think of it, quantizing the graces to fit into a sixteenth-note's duration:

[image]

There should also be implications about emphasis, besides simple timing. For both ornaments, the actual beat should be the strongest note, and the graces should be de-emphasized. Resist the urge, for example, to blurt out the latter grace notes just because they appear to start a measure; instead lean into the the true downbeat.

Comment: OP's example is Chopin, where this is good advice. For Bach, though, the grace notes should start on the beat.

Comment: I think you’ve got the order wrong for the prall trill, i.e. the first two notes should be fast.

Comment: @Peter Also in Bach style the prall trill would be executed as a full trillo.

Comment: @Lazy Good point, that's probably true. Though probably "three equal triplet-style notes" is also an option?